# Change class API depending on template parameter at class creation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I was looking to create a class that under specific template instantiation would expose a different API. It has common functions, but a few should be disabled in the case that the user will use a specific instantiation of the class. Something like this:

```
VarApi<T1> v1;
v1.common();
v1.funcA1();
// v1.funcA2(); // ERROR
v1.funcA1_2();

VarApi<T2> v2;
v1.common();
// v2.funcA1(); // ERROR
v2.funcA2();
v2.funcA1_2();

VarApi<T3> v3;
v3.common();
// v2.funcA1(); // ERROR
// v2.funcA2(); // ERROR
// v1.funcA1_2(); // ERROR
```

I found that you could achieve this with `SFINAE` and `std::enable_if` like this:

```
enum Type { T1, T2, T3 };

template <Type TType> struct VarApi {
    void common() { }

    template <Type T = TType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<T == T1>::type>
    void funcA1() { }

    template <Type T = TType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<T == T2>::type >
    void funcA2() { }

    template <Type T = TType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<T == T1 || T == T2>::type >
    void funcA1_2() { }

    template <Type T = TType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<T == T3>::type >
    void funcA3() { }
};
```

This works and achieves the functionality above. The problem is that the user can still override this with:

```
VarApi<T2> v2;
v2.funcA1<T1>(); // NOT ERROR
```

**Is there a way to prevent this case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works and achieves the functionality above. The problem is that the user can still override this with:
>
> ```
> VarApi<T2> v2;
> v2.funcA1<T1>(); // NOT ERROR
> ```
>
> Is there a way to prevent this case?

Sure.

You can impose that `T` and `TType` are the same type

```
template <Type T = TType,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
                           std::is_same<T, T1>::value
                        && std::is_same<T, TType>::value>::type>
void funcA1() { }
```

This prevent the template "hijacking".

Comment: Perfect. So simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit inheritance to provide desired functions. With CRTP, you access functionality of the original class in the `func_provider` by `self` pointer.

```
template<class T, class Derived> struct func_provider;

template<class Derived>
struct func_provider<int, Derived> {
    void funcA1() {
        auto self = static_cast<Derived*>(this);

        // do something with self
    }
};
template<class Derived> struct func_provider<double, Derived> { void funcA2() {} };

template<class T>
struct foo : public func_provider<T, foo<T>> {};

int main() {
    foo<int> f;
    foo<double> g;
    f.funcA1();
    // f.funcA2(); // Error
    g.funcA2();
    // g.funcA1(); // Error
}
```

**EDIT:**

This version allows the user to implement function for multiple types in one place, user can combine types together:

```
template<class... Ts> struct types {};

template<class Types, class T> struct is_in : public std::false_type {};
template<class... Ts, class T>
struct is_in<types<T, Ts...>, T> : public std::true_type {};
template<class... Ts, class T0, class T>
struct is_in<types<T0, Ts...>, T> : public is_in<types<Ts...>, T> {};

template<class Derived, bool B, class T> struct func_provider {};
template<class Derived, class T, class... Ts>
struct func_collector
    : public func_provider<Derived, is_in<Ts, T>::value, Ts>...
{};


// implement functions for int
template<class Derived>
struct func_provider<Derived, true, types<int>> {
    void funcA1() {
        auto self = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        // do something with self
    }
};

// implement functions for double
template<class Derived>
struct func_provider<Derived, true, types<double>> { void funcA2() {} };

// implement functions for both int and double
template<class Derived>
struct func_provider<Derived, true, types<int, double>> { void funcA1_2() {} };

template<class T>
struct foo : public func_collector<foo<T>, T,
    // pull desired functions
    types<int>, types<double>, types<int, double>>
{
    void common() {}
};

int main() {
    foo<int> f;
    foo<double> g;
    f.common();
    f.funcA1();
    f.funcA1_2();
    // f.funcA2(); // Error
    g.funcA2();
    g.funcA1_2();
    // g.funcA1(); // Error
}
```

Comment: "> But then my structures are virtual." no, there are no virtuals involved here.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox if your structures are virtual, please edit the question to reflect the actual complexity of the problem. Otherwise, we just try to solve what you told us. Examples must be minimal, but complete.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier There will be if i want to have common functionality shared, unless i re-implement everything in every specialization ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox not really. You can use friend functions or base classes for that.

Comment: put the common functionality in a `func_provider_base` and make `foo` or all your `func_provider` inherit from it and there won't be any virtuals.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox You can use CRTP, only those functionality related to `funcA1` and `funcA2` are moved to the provider.

Comment: Can you show how to use this to achieve the functionality shown in the question related to a function that can be used over some common but not all types, like in the `funcA1_2` case?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox What exactly do you want ? Only combination (`T == T1 || T == T2`) or other more complicated condition ?

Comment: @liliscent The question is pretty clear right? I want to be able to do combinations of functionality. So in the example there is a function that can be used by `T1 & 2` but not by 3. How can I adapt your solution to achieve that? I made the example in the question more clear to highlight this case.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Why do you think it's clear ? You can use `enable_if` on much more complicated conditions than simple combination.

Comment: @liliscent Yes, and it works in my solution with the exception of the problem that the user can overide the function call directly. In your solution I cant see a way to achieve the behaviour of `funcA1_2` without doing some sort of multiple inheritance special class or something.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox If you only want to combine some specific types, it's easy to adapt. But if you want some arbitrarily complex condition, it's not easy. BTW, your solution unnecessarily make those function a template, this has a huge impact on overload resolution.

Comment: @liliscent So far this solution doesn't have the functionality explicitly shown in the question (ie. the first example). I am not looking for a solution to an arbitrary problem, just this one. Can you show your solution adapted to do what mine does exactly minus the bad behaviour of of the user calling `v2.funcA1<T1>();` explicitly?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox could you put a complete code snippet online ? I fail to see why you should have to call `foo.functionality::function()` explicitely. It's just a base class, its members will be available as `foo.function()`

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Sorry, you are right. I was thinking of the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

One way to achieve what you ask for is to use tempalte specialization and dependent base classes to offer the optional functionalities.

```
// I'm using E for enum. I find TType a bit misleading, since T usually stands for Type
template< Type EType > 
struct VarApiBase { }; // empty by default

template< >
struct VarApiBase<T1> {
  void funcA1() { }
};

template< >
struct VarApiBase<T2> {
  void funcA2() { }
};

template <Type TType>
struct VarApi : VarApiBase<TType> {
  void funcA1_2() { }
};

template <>
struct VarApi<T3> { };
```

I'm not particularly fond of this solution. Because it becomes complex to provide shared functions (I put `funcA1_2` in VarApi, and not in the base, and then specialized VarApi again to disable it for T3, but this is forcing you to explicitly specialize every time you add a new EType value. You could get around it with an enabler for the specialization, but it again become complex if you have more intricate sharing).

If you need it, you can give `VarApiBase` access to `VarApi` by declaring it a friend in `VarApi`.

#### Solution 2

As a cheap alternative to all of this, you may just add a `static_assert` inside your functions:

```
template <Type ETypeInner = EType >
void funcA1_2() {
  static_assert(ETypeInner==EType);
  static_assert(EType == T1 || EType == T2);
}
```

If you really need SFINAE, you can still put the `==T1 || ==T2` condition in the template

```
template <Type ETypeInner = EType,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<ETypeInner == T1 || ETypeInner == T2>::type >
void funcA1_2() {
  static_assert(ETypeInner==EType);
}
```

but be aware it will make compilation slower.

#### Solution 3

Probably, the cleanest way would be to have explicit specializations and utility functions.

In VarApi.h:

```
struct VarApiImpl;

template< Type EType > 
struct VarApi; // undefined

// Ideally, VarApiCommon shouldn't need to be a template
template< Type EType >
struct VarApiCommon {
  // you can put here members and functions which common to all implementations, just for convenience.
  void common() { /* ... */ }
private:
  // You can do this if you need access to specialization-specific members.
  // Ideally, if a function is common, it should only need common members, though.
  VarApi<EType> & Derived() { return static_cast<VarApi<EType>&>(*this); }
  VarApi<EType> const& Derived() const { return static_cast<VarApi<EType> const&>(*this); }
};

template<> 
struct VarApi<T1> : VarApiCommon<T1> {
  friend VarApiImpl;
  friend VarApiCommon<T1>;
  void funcA1();
  void funcA1_2();
};

template<> 
struct VarApi<T2> : VarApiCommon<T2> {
  friend VarApiImpl;
  friend VarApiCommon<T2>;
  void funcA2();
  void funcA1_2();
};

template<> 
struct VarApi<T3> : VarApiCommon<T3> {
  friend VarApiCommon<T3>;
};
```

In VarApi.cpp:

```
struct VarApiImpl final {
  // Here go the functions which are only shared by some specializations
  template< Type EType >
  static void funcA1_2(VarApi<EType>& vapi) {
  // Just for sanity. Since this function is private to the .cpp, it should be impossible to call it inappropriately
    static_assert(EType==T1 || EType==T2);
    // ...
  }
};
void VarApi<T1>::funcA1() { /* ... */ }
void VarApi<T1>::funcA1_2() { VarApiImpl::funcA1_2(*this); }

void VarApi<T2>::funcA2() { /* ... */ }
void VarApi<T2>::funcA1_2() { VarApiImpl::funcA1_2(*this); }
```

It gets as verbose as C++ can be, but at least you have explicit interfaces clearly stating what's offered and what's not, without having to read a bunch of `enable_if`s.

#### Solution 4

Ultimately, I would suggest you to look more carefully at your requirements, to see if they can't be expressed as a proper class hierarchy, based on the features each enum value represents. C++ even has virtual inheritance, if you need to avoid duplicate bases. For instance, that'd be possible in your example:

```
struct VarApiCommon {
  void common();
};

struct VarApi12 : VarApiCommon {
  void funcA1_2();
};

template< Type EType >
struct VarApi; // undefined

template<>
struct VarApi<T1> : VarApi12 {
  void funcA1();
};

template<>
struct VarApi<T2> : VarApi12 {
  void funcA2();
};

template<>
struct VarApi<T2> : VarApiCommon {
  void funcA3();
};
```

If you had a funcA2_3, for instance, you may still be able to do it this way:

```
struct VarApiCommon {
  void common();
};

struct VarApi12 : virtual VarApiCommon {
  void funcA1_2();
};

struct VarApi23 : virtual VarApiCommon {
  void funcA2_3();
};

template< Type EType >
struct VarApi; // undefined

template<>
struct VarApi<T1> : VarApi12 {
  void funcA1();
};

template<>
struct VarApi<T2> : VarApi12, VarApi23 {
  void funcA2();
};

template<>
struct VarApi<T2> : VarApi23 {
  void funcA3();
};
```

Much depends on the members.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is based on you being able to provide the implementation, but wanting to hide it.

Have a base implementation, which implements everything

```
template <class X> class Base
{
public:
    void A();
    void B();
    void C();
    void D();
    void E();
};
```

Have a derived class which inherits protected, but then publishes public all the common methods from the base

```
template <class X> class Mid: protected Base<X>
{
public:
    using Base::A;
    using Base::B;
    using Base::C;
    // D & E are contentious
};
```

Have the actual published class, where each variant T1, T2, T3 is specialised.
These classes all publicly inherit from the second class, but then public friend publish the methods they do support.

```
template <class X> class Top: public Mid<X> {};
template <> class Top<X1>: public Mid<X1>
{
public:
    using Base::D;
    // Can't get E
};
template <> class Top<X2>: public Mid<X2>
{
public:
    // Can't get D
    using Base::E;
};
```

Gains: The methods you want to hide are not accessible. There is no template function magic.

Losses: The rules for publishing are arbitrary, and not driven by 'readable' FINAE at all. You also can't easily use inheritance to build rules either, though you might be able to do a LikeX second template argument.